# Having trouble with namespaces in XML lookups, using DOMCategory

Tags: groovy, closures, xml-namespaces

When trying to lookup a certain node in an XML document, I'm having trouble with the namespaces. Here's the code I'm using:

**The simplified XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map:sitemap xmlns:map="http://apache.org/cocoon/sitemap/1.0">
    <map:components>
        <map:generators>
            ...
            <map:generator name="FinsXMLGenerator"/>
        </map:generators>
    ...
```

I'm trying to receive the following node:

```
<map:generator name="FinsXMLGenerator"/>
```

**Using the following DOMCategory closure:**

```
def closure = { sitemap -> 
    def result = sitemap.'map:sitemap'.'map:components'.'map:generators'.'map:generator'.'@name'.find({ 
        it.text() == 'FinsXMLGenerator' 
    }); 
    return result; 
}
```

I've written a lot of closures like this without namespaces in the XML, which work perfectly fine. But the namespaces destroy everything.
I don't get any errors, the result is just null. Can anyone help me fix the path - e.g.

```
sitemap.'map:sitemap'...
```

I'm using Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def node = use( DOMCategory ) {
  sitemap.'map:components'.'map:generators'.'map:generator'.find {
    it.getAttribute( 'name' ) == 'FinsXMLGenerator'
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, finally it works, thanks tim! Haha, I noticed you're the person who answered all my questions so far ^^